# ssh2 node js sftp protocol Error Handshake failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, ssh2-sftp

Hello i have a little problem, i developped a script sftp client with node js that connect to an sftp server and grab some files, i tested it with my local server its working, but when i tried to use it with production server i received this error :

> Error: Handshake failed: no matching key exchange algorithm

i already generated the rsa key using `ssh-keygen`

here is the relevant part of the script :

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var args = process.argv.slice(2);

var connSettings = {
    host: args[0] || '127.0.0.1',
    port: args[1] || 22,
    username: args[2] || 'karim',
    password: args[3] || 'karimos',
    algorithms: {
        hmac: ['hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96']
    }

};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also had the same problem and solved it by adding the following:

```
algorithms: {
        kex: [
          "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1",
          "ecdh-sha2-nistp256",
          "ecdh-sha2-nistp384",
          "ecdh-sha2-nistp521",
          "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256",
          "diffie-hellman-group14-sha1"
        ],
        cipher: [
          "3des-cbc",
          "aes128-ctr",
          "aes192-ctr",
          "aes256-ctr",
          "aes128-gcm",
          "aes128-gcm@openssh.com",
          "aes256-gcm",
          "aes256-gcm@openssh.com"
        ],
        serverHostKey: [
          "ssh-rsa",
          "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256",
          "ecdsa-sha2-nistp384",
          "ecdsa-sha2-nistp521"
        ],
        hmac: [
          "hmac-sha2-256",
          "hmac-sha2-512",
          "hmac-sha1"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

For myself, I added `debug: console.log` to my config object. This output more about the connection attempt.

```js
{
    "port": 22,
    "host": "test.test.com",
    "user": "test",
    "password": "******",
    "debug": console.log
}
```

> Handshake: (remote) KEX method: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1

> Handshake: No matching key exchange algorithm

Based on this error I updated my config's algorithm:

```js
{
    "port": 22,
    "host": "test.test.com",
    "user": "test",
    "password": "******",
    "algorithms": {
        "kex": [
            "diffie-hellman-group14-sha1","diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1"
        ]
    }
}
```

After adding this algorithm the connection was successful on my machine

Answer (score 2):

You may edit your /etc/ssh/sshd configuration file, on your server, in order to allow the key authentication method :)

Comment: can you give me some reference, but i have used filezilla to connect to the server and its worked, also i tried without the     `algorithms: {
        hmac: ['hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96']
    }`
and its didn't worked

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to upgrade the ssh server on the server you're connecting to so that a more secure configuration can be had. This is the best/most secure solution.

If you cannot make changes on this server and you absolutely need to connect, then you *can* explicitly set the `kex` to a list of key exchange methods you want to support (valid algorithm names can be found in the [`ssh2-streams` documentation](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/b1c024db9df415ad7b1f5d9e36e66c3af33451fd/README.md#ssh2stream-methods)). For example:

```
algorithms: {
  kex: [ ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing your algorithms declaration to...?

`algorithms: {
    serverHostKey: [ 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96' ],
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Added "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1",
i've got comment error **unknown DH group**

```
"kex": [
  "ecdh-sha2-nistp256",
  "ecdh-sha2-nistp384",
  "ecdh-sha2-nistp521",
  "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256",
  "diffie-hellman-group14-sha1",
  "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1",
  "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"
],
"cipher": [
  "3des-cbc",
  "aes128-ctr",
  "aes192-ctr",
  "aes256-ctr",
  "aes128-gcm",
  "aes128-gcm@openssh.com",
  "aes256-gcm",
  "aes256-gcm@openssh.com"
],
"serverHostKey": [
  "ssh-rsa",
  "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256",
  "ecdsa-sha2-nistp384",
  "ecdsa-sha2-nistp521"
],
"hmac": [
  "hmac-sha2-256",
  "hmac-sha2-512",
  "hmac-sha1"
]
```

Blockquote

```
 "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1",
```